# Is it possible to contain more than one leaflet/mapbox map in a single HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, leaflet, mapbox

I am working on a Single Page Application which has two maps which look something like this:

**Markup:**

```
<div id = "page1>
  <div id='map'></div>
</div>

<div id = "page2>
  <div id='map2'></div>
</div>
```

**Code:**

```
  L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmV5bmVyb25nIiwiYSI6ImNpZzB2ZWs4MDBpdG90emt2ZjZ0bHI5dWEifQ.sP6kg2gGfN7NBAOYRasyeA';
  var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets');
  var map2 = L.mapbox.map('map2', 'mapbox.streets');
```

However, the maps don't work when doing this. Is there a way to do this or is it simply not possible to have more than one leaflet/mapbox map in a single HTML page?

Comment: It should work. Make sure your HTML syntax is correct (looks like you have missing quotes `"` after `page1` and `page2` id's.

Comment: just checked, that was an error when typing it into stackoverflow. the thing is that map1 works fine on its own, but upon adding the line `map2 = L.mapbox.map('map2', 'mapbox.streets');
` the whole thing stops working

Answer (score 0):

I believe the scripts will clash if you have them in one containing div. There may be a way to manipulate the script to work. One way to fix them would be to go through and check that in the script for `map2` make sure that 'map' is not mentioned as this could cause the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work: https://jsfiddle.net/rfrq9f1g/

Make sure you have properly set CSS size (`height` at least, `width` if possible) for `#map` and `#map2` div containers.